# How to use TypeScript ambient declaration interfaces in interface declared in d.ts file

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want to do a helper in .ts file like:

```
class ResponseHelper implements IResponseHelper {...}
```

and IResponseHelper is simple .d.ts file with

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import * as express from 'express'
interface IResponseHelper {
    toStandartResponse(response: mongoose.Promise<any>, res: express.Response): mongoose.Promise<any>;
}
```

as you can see params in toStandartResponse are coming from mongoose which is ambiently declared. So this if fine but if i do so I cannot us it with 'implements' like class ResponseHelper implements IResponseHelper because I got errror 'Could not find symbol IResponseHelper in external module ResponseHelper' in other words compiler cannot see d.ts file. 
If i remove import statements from d.ts. file everuthing is ok but i cannot specify response types then.

Is there any way to use it all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe when you use `import` in makes the file a module, so you must `export` any members you want visible:

```
export interface IResponseHelper { }
```

Now you can `import` it from other files:

```
import {IResponseHelper} from "./IResponseHelper";

class ResponseHelper implements IResponseHelper { }
```

Comment: I will try this, but it is strange because .d.ts are definition files and has no generated code. So what will be an output for javascript in this case. It should cause error that module does not exists or smthng.